# Qual vantagem em usar a última versão do .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Por padrão o meu Visual Studio seleciona .NET Framework 4.6.1 ao iniciar um novo projeto, mas há alguma vantagem em selecionar a última versão? (4.7.1)

Comment: A vantagem de ter sempre a versão mais recente, é ter as novas features, correção de bugs, otimizações, etc. Mas ter a versão mais recente também significa estar sujeito a novos problemas que não foram percebidos antes de disponibilizar ao público (mas são raros)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depende do que você chama de vantagem. Mas ele tem várias correções de *bugs* e algumas *features*.

Várias características do C# 7 só funcionam com esta versão (outras nem com ela, está ficando pra trás), como tuplas por exemplo. APIs novas do Windows também só estão disponíveis nele. Há algumas melhorias no Windows Forms e WPF, além de UWP que faz parte das melhorias do Windows. Não farei uma lista extensa de tudo o que tem novo, mas tem [anúncio oficial das principais inovações](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/04/05/announcing-the-net-framework-4-7/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Se quiser tem os [detalhes de cada *release*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/whats-new/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Já saiu a versão 4.8 e recomendo o uso dela se ainda ficará no .NET Framework. [É a última versão que será lançada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101), jamais haverá evolução.

O C# 8 roda algumas coisas no .NET 4.8, mas não tudo e nunca rodará. Fica claro que a Microsoft não fará muitos investimentos no .NET Framework e ele vai aos poucos entrando em modo legado, ainda mais com .NET Core 3.0 que praticamente resolve o que faltava nele para que o .NET não seja mais necessário. Falo isto há bastante tempo, algumas pessoas diziam que eu estava errado, agora dá para ver mais nitidamente que o futuro do C# é só em cima do Core. Na verdade já foi anunciado oficialmente que este é o único caminho viável.

Leia: [O .NET Framework está morto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101).